# Story Identification: A sci-fi book about human/animal hybrids or clones

Tags: story-identification, space, clones, animals

I'm trying to identify a sci-fi book I read in my youth in 1970s.

#### Key plot points:

1. It was a saga of the far future where humanity was blended with many different animal types, so characters were partly like lions, tigers etc.
2. I think they were also clones, and their names included numbers to show what generation they were.
3. The main protagonist was called something like 'adam 25' and he was the prince of a royal family.

#### Timeline and other relevant  info

I read this at some point from early to mid 1970s, alongside things like 'Shadow of heaven' and 'Eyes of the overworld'.

Comment: "You look like a baboon" ... "Thanks, Got that look from my mother". I already like that story.

Comment: The first plot point made me think of John Crowley's "[Beasts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beasts_(Crowley_novel))", but the others don't match that.

Comment: The first plot point made me think of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumentality_of_Mankind

Comment: Bush warned us!

Answer (score 2):

This is likely *Days of Glory* by Brian Stableford (1971). It involves beast-people (combos with lions, etc) and a character named ‘Adam December.’

Back cover: “Ten millennia had passed since the creation of the Beasts, and those ten thousand years had obliterated the original purpose of Adam December and the construct surgeons.

Ten millennia had passed since the word WAR was forgotten and remembered; and that word wiped out ten thousand years of peaceful coexistence.

Ten millennia, one thousand decades, ten thousand years .. and for the first time Humans and Beasts were dying throughout the galaxy.

But it should have been expected: man had created the Beasts in his own image, and unfortunately, the Beasts were just like him.”

[image: book cover]